# Looping through a dataframes, collecting data, creating new dataframes

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector, rdcomclient

I have the below dataframe (in reality it spans a couple hundred rows of the same data).

```
project_number  hours  team_member    project_lead    team_member_email
      RR711-132     4   Isaac Bell    Dan Case          ib@blank.com
      RR711-135    10   Isaac Bell    Lawrence Cowan    ib@blank.com
     USU887-101    50   Keith Olsen   Aaron Anderson    aa@blank.com
      VE902-102    30   Chase Harmon  Isaac Bell        ch@blank.com
      SS99-133     50   Chase Harmon  Jack Spain        ch@blank.com
```

The goal is to send an email to the team member, that includes a table with the details of the project_number, hours, and the project lead.

I am using RDCOMClient to send out the email, and the "purrr" package to loop over the vectors.

```
mail_fun <- function(name, mail) {
  outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
  ## configure  email parameter
  outMail[["To"]] = mail
  outMail[["subject"]] = "Project hours for next week"
  outMail[["HTMLBody"]] = paste0("Dear ", name, "<p>Testing sending hours through R</>")
  ## send it
  outMail$Send()
}

map2(test.df$team_member, test.df$email, ~mail_fun(name = .x, mail = .y))
```

I know the code needs modification, but the looping works as well as the sending of the email. What I cannot figure out, is how to create a table (dataframe) that is specifically for the team_member and have it sent through email.

For example, an email would be sent to Isaac Bell, and in the body of that email would be a table that looked like this (I don't know how to make a good-looking table here):

```
Isaac,

You have been assigned the following hours to the following project for this week:

Project Number     Hours       Project Lead
RR711-132           4           Dan Case
RR711-135           10          Lawrence Cowan
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use the `split()` function. Create dataframes within a list for each individual team member and then loop through those dataframes and send the email.